# How to get a recurrence relation from an expression with maximum

Tags: recurrence-relations, maxima-minima

There is a certain function $F(r,s)$ (where $r\geq -1$ and $s\geq 0$ are integers) that satisfies the following relation:

$$
\max\big[2 F(r,s) - F(r-1,s) - F(r-1,s-1)~~~,~~~F(r+1,s+1) - F(r-1,s)\big] =  0
\\
F(r,0)=1 ~~~~~ \forall r\geq 0
\\
F(0,s)=0 ~~~~~ \forall s\geq 1
\\
F(-1,s)=0 ~~~~~ \forall s\geq 0
$$

Is there a way to get from this relation, an explicit recurrence relation on $F(r,s)$, so that I can numerically compute e.g. $F(1000,1000)$?

NOTE: I had a similar function $G(r,s)$ that satisfies the following similar relation:

$$
\max\big[2 G(r,s) - G(r-1,s) - G(r-1,s-1)~~~,~~~G(r,s) - G(r-2,s-1)\big] =  0
\\
G(r,0)=1 ~~~~~ \forall r\geq 0
\\
G(0,s)=0 ~~~~~ \forall s\geq 1
\\
G(-1,s)=0 ~~~~~ \forall s\geq 0
$$
Here I managed to find the solution myself. There are two cases: either the leftmost term is larger, and then $G(r,s)=[G(r-1,s) - G(r-1,s-1)]/2$, or the rightmost term is larger, and then $G(r,s)=G(r-2,s-1)$. Therefore, the recurrence relation is:

$$
G(r,s) = \min\big[ 
[G(r-1,s) - G(r-1,s-1)]/2
~~~,~~~
G(r-2,s-1)
\big]
$$

From this relation and the boundary conditions, it is easy to compute $G(1000,1000)$.

But, this does not work with $F$. How can I get a recurrence relation on $F$?

Comment: Do you mean $r,s$ integers, or $r,s$ non negative integers?

Comment: It is not clear to me how the case you mention for $G$ is handled. In order the recurrence to work, you need the values of $G(1,s)$ for all $s$, and there are restrictions on these values.

Comment: @san I see what you mean - another row of $r$ is needed because of the $r-2$. I added the row where $r=-1$.

Comment: It is also not clear if for example $(r,s)=(0,0)$ satisfies the relation. The relation implies that $F(r+1,s+1)−F(r−1,s)\le 0$, which makes sense for $(r,s)=(0,0)$, but $2F(r,s)−F(r−1,s)−F(r−1,s−1)$ is not defined, so the maximum is not defined.

Comment: You should define $F(r,s)$ for $r,s\ge -1$ but require the recursion formula only for $r,s\ge 0$.

Comment: In that case you must define $F(r,-1)=1$ for $r\ge 0$ and you can define $F(-1,-1)=2$.

Comment: The previous case you solved has a unique solution. However, with the new recursion formula there are multiple solutions (assuming the condition of my previous comments). For example, the function G is a solution (it satisfies the recursion formula), but also $F(r,s)=G(r-1,s)$ is a solution. I'm pretty sure that you can vary the parameter t=F(2,1) freely between 1/2 (first solution F=G) and 0 (the second solution), but I haven't done the full computations. Moreover, you can also vary other entries of F. What can be proven is that F(r,s)=0 for $r\le s-1$ if $r\ge 1$ and $(r,s)$ is not $(2,1)$.

Comment: @san the last comment is very interesting. I did not think there might be multiple solutions.

Comment: The solution given by Linalg is yet another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bootstrap the recursion and see if you find a pattern. The easiest way to read this post is by drawing a 2x2 grid and taking notes in it.

Your expression is:
$$\max\left\{ 2 F(r,s) - F(r-1,s) - F(r-1,s-1), \quad F(r+1,s+1) - F(r-1,s)\right\} =  0$$
Due to the argument $s-1$, you cannot fill in $s=0$. Since $F(r-1,s)$ occurs in both terms, you can take it out of the max expression:
$$\max\left\{ 2 F(r,s) - F(r-1,s-1), \quad F(r+1,s+1)\right\} =  F(r-1,s) \qquad (1)$$

For $r=0$ and $s \geq 1$, (1) means:
$$\max\left\{ 0, F(1,s+1)\right\} =  0$$
so $F(1,s+1) \leq 0$.

For $r=1$ and $s \geq 1$, (1) means:
$$\max\left\{ 2 F(1,s) - F(0,s-1), \quad F(2,s+1)\right\} =  0,$$
so $F(2,s) \leq 0$ and $2 F(1,s) \leq F(0,s-1)$, with equality for at least one of them.

For $s=1$ and $r \geq 1$, (1) means:
$$\max\left\{ 2 F(r,1) - 1, \quad F(r+1,2)\right\} =  F(r-1,1),$$
so $F(r,1)\leq0.5+0.5F(r-1,1)$ and $F(r+1,2)\leq F(r-1,1)$, with equality for at least one of them

There is no pattern that arises, but
$$F(r,s)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } r\geq 0 \text{ and } s=0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
satisifies the recursion.

Comment: Indeed there is a trivial solution that I did not notice. Thanks!